# duplicated shapes on circle path? Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, alignment

I am wanting to create lots of small circles evenly spread to form a circle and am wondering what the best way to go about it is?
I am thinking the blend tool? Is there a way to get it to follow a circular path?
Otherwise I am just duplicating and using smart guides to align and then copying and mirroring to the other side. Just wondering if there is a more automatic way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circle with a **dashed stroke** having rounded caps ....

[image]

- Stroke weight controls the size of the "dots" 
  <sup>(i.e. an 8pt stoke means the "dots" will have an 8pt diameter)</sup>
- Rounded caps makes them "dots"
- 0 dash makes the dash not have a length, resulting in "dots"
- Gap controls the space between "dots" 
  <sup>(center to center - so gap minus stroke weight = space between dots. In this case 15 - 8 = 7pts)</sup>

You can then cut the circle however you need. 
Or simply apply the dashed stroke to a path you already have.

[image]

If you then need each "dot" as an individual object... 
... choose `Object > Expand Appearance`, and then `Object > Expand` from the menu.
You may need to then `Object > Ungroup` and/or `Object > Compound Path > Release` as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Draw a circle, and select it
2. Press <kbd>R</kbd> to select the Rotate Tool
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click a centre of rotation
4. Type in a rotation angle in the Rotate dialog
5. Hit Copy
6. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> repeatedly to duplicate and copy the transform around the circle

For example

[image]